# how to "convert date time timezone value in ORACLE select query"

Tags: mysql, database, oracle10g

I am migrating DB from **MySQL** to **Oracle**, so need to write similar query in oracle.

Following is the MySQL query, how to convert this to Oracle:

```
SELECT convert_tz(datetime, Etc/UTC, America/Los_Angeles) AS datetime1 from XYZ
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timezone conversion in PLSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328907/timezone-conversion-in-plsql)

Comment: What data type is your original value - date, timestamp, or timestamp with [local] time zone? And what data type do you want to end up with? It would probably be helpful to include sample data and expected results - though this will almost certainly be a duplicate; more info will just help identify the best one to close this against.

Answer (score 0):

```
select FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2005-09-11 01:50:42', '5:00')
from dual;
```

**timestamp_value**
The value to convert to a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE value.
**time_zone_value**
The time zone used to convert timestamp_value to a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE value.

```
11-Sep-05 01.50.42.000000 AM +05:00
```